# How to Draw a polygon on an image in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, drawing, shapes, skiasharp

I want to draw a polygon on image in xamarin .
I have implemented it in C# windows form .
here is a screenshot of what I did using windows form in c# and I want to do using xamarin .

I searched about this and I found that SkiaSharp Library may do this but still I do not found how to do this using xamarin .

and here is the C# code that I used to draw the polygon but I need to convert it into xamarin.

```
private void boxImg_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        if (LstCalibratedPrev.Count != 0)
        {
            Pen thikpen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255), 3);
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(thikpen, LstCalibratedPrev.ToArray());
            Polygon pgon = new Polygon(LstCalibratedPrev.ToArray());
            foreach (PointF corner in LstCalibratedPrev)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)corner.X - object_radius   , (int)corner.Y - object_radius,    2 * object_radius + 1   , 2 * object_radius + 1);   //smaller rect
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle((int)corner.X - object_radius2 , (int)corner.Y - object_radius2,   2 * object_radius2 + 1  , 2 * object_radius2 + 1);  
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.WhiteSmoke, rect);
                Pen Circle = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255), 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Circle, rect2);
            }
        }
        if (LstCalibratedPrev.Count != 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color2Transparent(T, Color.Black)), LstCalibratedPrev.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/circle

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said whether you are using Xamarin.Forms (XF) or classic Xamarin. Either way, you could either draw the lines using the native sdk libraries for each platform (and encapsulate that in custom renderers if you are using XF, as shown by @Crunch) or use a third party cross platform drawing library such as [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)  https://skia.org/.

I'd recommend using SkiaSharp. It is very powerful and fast, is a truly cross platform 2D graphics library, and can be used in 'classic' projects as well as XF. It's is well worth the investment to learn how to use it. Most of the examples you'll find are for XF but can be adapted for classic Xamarin. SkiaSharp draws in a SKCanvasView which you can position on top of the the view you want to draw over. SKCanvasView subclasses the root View class for each platform so can be added as a Subview in iOS or to any layout in Android (both in code and axml), or to a XF layout in XF.

Here are a couple of references to help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/

https://github.com/mattleibow/SkiaSharpDemo

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin forms you can do it with [custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction).

In app shared add this to view:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Direction="Column">
            <controls:ImagePainterControl
                HeightRequest="500"
                WidthRequest="750"
                ImageSource="{Binding ImgSrc}"
            </controls:ImagePainterControl>
        </StackLayout >      
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Control:

```cs
    public class ImagePainterControl: ContentView
    {
        public string ImageSource{ get; set; }
    }
```

Custom renderer in android:

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(ImagePainterControl), typeof(ImagePainterRenderer))]
namespace Nabil.App.Droid.Renderers
{
    class ImagePainterRenderer: ViewRenderer<ImagePainterControl, Android.Views.View>
    {
        private string _imageSource { get; set; }

        public HouseRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {            
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HouseCanvas> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null) return;

            var view = e.NewElement as ImagePainterControl;
            _imageSource = view.ImageSource;
        }

        protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
             /* 
             * get the view where canvas will be drawn.
             * Height and width of view is set in XAML with "HeightRequest" and "WidthRequest"
             * We can't set this props in here
             */
            var rect = new Rect();
            this.GetDrawingRect(rect);

            // Set your logic of shape, width and height of your polygon here
            var topLine = rect.Width() * 0.8; 
            var bottomLine = rect.Width() * 0.8; 
            var leftLine = rect.Height() * 0.5;
            var rightLine = rect.Height() * 0.5;

            var polyStroke = new Paint
            {
                Color = _strokeColor,
                StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round,
                StrokeWidth = 5
            };

            var polyCircle = new Paint
            {
                Color = _strokeColor,
                StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round,
                StrokeWidth = 3
            };

            // Set drawing logic here (0,0 is top left)
            canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, polyStroke ); // top line
            canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, polyStroke ); // bottom line
            canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, polyStroke ); // left line
            canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, polyStroke ); // right line
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // top left circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // top mid circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // top right circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // right circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // left circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // bottom left circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // bottom mid circle
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, 15, polyCircle); // bottom right circle

            /* https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/24533/#Comment_24533 */
            var img = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(_imageSource);
            img = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(img, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), true);

            canvas.DrawBitmap(img, 0, 0, new Paint());

            img.Recycle();
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
```